# My app's main view doesn't resize to fill the screen when the device is rotated

Tags: ios, iphone, rotation, screen-rotation

Recently I ran into an issue with my app when changing the device's orientation.

This is my main ViewController (let's call it VC1) in portrait mode:

[image]

Now if you push / present any viewcontroller (let's call that VC2), rotate the screen while in VC2, and return back to the previous view (VC1), this is what I get:

[image]

Why doesn't VC1 rotate correctly like it should? This issue happens throughout the whole app and with any two views. I honestly have no idea what might be causing this or where to look, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What constraints have you added? Are you using an actual device or a simulator?

Comment: Like I said, this happens for the whole application, and for all viewcontrollers, on both an actual device and the simulator.

Comment: @rmaddy actually this happens to all views, not just the main view.

Comment: @Malfunction, Please let us know if you are using AutoLayout or not for setting the frames of all the views/viewcontrollers. This kind of thing normally happens because of hardcoded values for frames(CGRect).

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri Yes, I'm using AutoLayout.

Comment: Then, can you please post your constraints code in any particular ViewController so that we can observe if there is anything wrong in it?

Comment: The application has over 20 viewcontrollers, and is displayed correctly in all orientations for all these viewcontrollers. The issue only happens when there is an orientation change, and is fixed by rotating the view again. I just don't see how this has anything to do with constraints.

Comment: Let's say your `viewA` is constrained to superview in the following way: `left = superview.left; right = superview.right; top = superview.top; bottom = superview.bottom`; Then this issue shouldn't come. If your constraints are in the following way  `centerX = superview.centerX; centerY = superview.centerY; width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width; height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height`. Then this issue will come. So, it depends on the constraints. That's why I asked you to post your constraints (Any ViewController). Please observe whether you made a mistake like that or not

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri That makes sense, but unfortunately that's not the issue here. The constraints are set up correctly. :(

Comment: Is the dot view owned by a child view controller?

Comment: @shallowThought What do you mean? The screenshot is of the application's main view controller.

Comment: I have recently seen this behaviour in a setup which would be: The square of dots is a view of a `dotViewController`, which is a `childViewController` of `lifeCalendarViewController`.

Comment: Have you added Splash screen for the devices ? It may cause the issue.

Comment: Please also share code that you using.

Comment: @RigelNetworksPvt.Ltd. Nope, no splash screen. And what part of the code should I share? This problem happens for the whole application and all its viewcontrollers.

Comment: First Add all required splash screens.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use constraints and autolayout? Can you post a screeen where constraints of the view are visible? I think there are some missing constraints

Answer (score -1):

your navigation bar is properly resize in portrait and landscape mode So The main problem is you didn't add trailing Constraints to your view.
Just Add you trailing constraints on your view in Storyboard.

Comment: Like I said in the question, this happens to all views in the whole app.

Comment: Did u Add Trailing constraints to all the views in the whole app.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the views - they are displayed correctly in both orientations. The issue arises when going back the navigation stack after an orientation change occurs - the app doesn't seem to change the orientation of the screens that are already on the stack.

Comment: Try to change orientation force fully when you back or refresh/reload constraints.